# How to detect discord user streaming activity update (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have this code to detect when someone's activity is set to streaming, but with the way that i have done it (i'm fairly sure there are better ways), i'm not sure how to detect when it it is no longer set to streaming and remove the role.

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    game = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.streaming"]
    if game:
      channel = client.get_channel(848003612121628682)
      guild = client.get_guild(762352010463936523)
      role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'Live!', guild.roles)
      await after.add_roles(role)
      await channel.send("<@427155509129379851> someone live")
      print(game[0].name)
      print(f'{after.name}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if `ActivityType.streaming` was in `before.activities` but isn't in `after.activities`

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    game = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.streaming"]
    if game:
        channel = client.get_channel(848003612121628682)
        guild = client.get_guild(762352010463936523)
        role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'Live!', guild.roles)
        await after.add_roles(role)
        await channel.send("<@427155509129379851> someone live")
        print(game[0].name)
        print(f'{after.name}')

    was_streaming = [i for i in before.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.streaming"]
    if not game and was_streaming:
        guild = client.get_guild(762352010463936523)
        role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'Live!', guild.roles)
        await after.remove_roles(role)
```